# Ubuntu SDK: Can't deploy to device

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I installed the Ubuntu SDK following the instructions given in 
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/platform/sdk/installing-the-sdk/ 
Afterwards I connected my Aquaris M10 (running Ubuntu Touch) and automatically created a Kit. After enabling developers mode, I connected my device with the computer and created a simple project (QML App with c++ plugin, qmake). When I run the Hello World project in Desktop mode everything works fine, but while running the program on the Tablet Kit I get the following error message:

> Schwerwiegender Fehler: /tmp/test3.username_0.1_armhf.click failed to install.
>   WARNING:root:Signature check failed, but installing anyway as requested
>   Cannot install /tmp/test3.username_0.1_armhf.click: Framework "ubuntu-sdk-15.04.5" not present on system (use --force-missing-framework option to override)
>
> Sdk-Launcher> Installing the application failed

What can I do to make the program run on my tablet? Since I'm knew to Qt and app development I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Try using "framework": "ubuntu-sdk-15.04.4" (change in manifest.json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pomsky suggested in hin comment I had to choose "ubuntu-sdk-15.04.4" in the manifest.json - File.